# Let ExpressJS know that pug/jade files are not static

Tags: javascript, express

ExpressJS considers my pug/jade files as static. So when I do that:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "assets"));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Express tries to get the index.pug from the assets folder. How can I tell Express that pug files are not static (or how to tell it to use the `assets` folder for all the static files except pug files)?

Comment: Typically, you'd store static files and template/view files in separate directories.

Comment: @robertklep That's what I ended up doing :) thanks

Comment: Separate for example your main html files in part. Header,body,footer. After that take create main pug page and include these separated files into main.pug